# Chrome apps: Will Chrome apps work on older versions of Chrome after December 2022?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

Google has decided to end the ability to open the **Chrome apps** on Windows and MacOS after December 2022. My question is if they will work on older versions of Chrome?

Comment: As long as you don't update your old Chrome and the old app/extension it will all work for you. Google doesn't even consider the older versions of their browser as existing, they only support the most recent stable version and a few recent versions in their extended LTS for enterprises.

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm! :) Do you know what is good for Chrome App migration? PWA doesn't work for me, because i need webviews in each opened tab in app.

Answer (score 0):

June 2022: Chrome Web Store will stop offering Chrome App installations for Windows, Mac, and Linux users.
July 2022: End support for Chrome Apps on Windows, Mac, and Linux.
March 2023: Chrome Apps will no longer be launchable on Windows, Mac, and Linux.
January 2025: End support for Chrome Apps on ChromeOS.

For more Info please visit below link

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/174381169?visit_id=638222337887590606-870330188&p=chrome_app_deprecation&rd=1